# What is the difference between J# and C#

Tags: java, c#, j#

I have been reading around about people using J#.

But my question is:
What is the difference between J# and C#?

OK, my understanding of J# is like C# but in Java. Am I correct in that?
Was J# before C#?

I hope someone can help me understand this better.

Comment: I am pretty sure J# came months or years *after* C#.

Comment: "People using J#"??? The `J#` tag has only 30 questions, including this one...

Comment: Check out this forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualjsharpgeneral/thread/3fbac9ac-c43a-4c7f-9fee-1bc1de2c6fc5

Comment: So, @BoltClock, you're saying that J# is newer than C#?

Comment: Wow, you learn something new everyday, haha. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`C#` is MS's ECMA standard langauge that borrows heavily from `C/C++/Java` (and a couple of concepts from Delphi).

`J#` is essentially a version of `J++` for the .NET platform. It accepts the Java-esque language that `J++` did but produces .NET code rather than `Java` bytecodes.

Comment: Thank you Neil. That gives me a much wider understanding

Answer (score 1):

J# was an implementation of the Java language on the .NET framework.  It has since been discontinued with no further developments or plans for development.

Answer (score 0):

J# is the updated version of j++, I think, which was MSs implementation of Java.

Comment: This is not true as Microsoft had there own Java VM like Sun's is to this day when Sun got the rights to Java they stoped MS from creating one My Dad still has the MS one as it is faster on windows than running the Sun version however Like the .Net Framework in windows the Sun Java Runtime has alot of code that is used in programs that lends code so to speak from the Java Compiled bins 
As .Net Applications dose not compile .Net they use it then they just make sure the client has a matching .Net so it can use them,
Java works same with the Sun version so new Java code just wont work in MS one